# Reading Object Property with CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

I'm using CakePHP for the first time and inside my controller I need to toggle the state of a property of an instance of my model:

```
function toggleAutoMark($id = null) {
    $this->Test->id = $id;
    $this->Test->saveField('automark', !$this->Test->read('automark'));
    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'tests', 'action' => 'view', $id));
}
```

I've no idea if I'm meant to be using a read() method, but this returns an array (which is not what I thought the docs said).

```
$this->Test->automark
```

doesn't work, presumably because the instance hasn't been loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are probably looking for

```
Model::field()
```

and therefore

```
$this->Test->field('automark');
```

although this is not a very good idea from a performance perspective.

Model::updateAll performs an atomic query which would suit you better here (see the documentation on that).